# Spooling ongoing items generated by Observable.FromEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

My goal here is to spool all items/notifications going from `IObservable<T>` for future subscribers.

E.g. if someone subscribes on a message stream, first he receives all messages which came prior to the subscription. Then he starts receiving new messages, whenever there are any. This should occur seamlessly, without repetitions and losses on the "boundary" between old and new messages.

I came up with following extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> WithHistory<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    var accumulator = new BlockingCollection<T>();

    source.Subscribe(accumulator.Add);

    return accumulator
        .GetConsumingEnumerable()
        .ToObservable()
        .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
}
```

As far as I tested it, it works:

```
class Generator<T>
{
    event Action<T> onPush;

    public IObservable<T> Items =>
        Observable.FromEvent<T>(d => onPush += d, d => onPush -= d);

    public void Push(T item) => onPush?.Invoke(item);
}

...

private static void Main()
{
    var g = new Generator<int>();
    var ongoingItems = g.Items;
    var allItems = g.Items.WithHistory();

    g.Push(1);
    g.Push(2);

    ongoingItems.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"Ongoing: got {x}"));
    allItems.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"WithHistory: got {x}"));

    g.Push(3);
    g.Push(4);
    g.Push(5);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The result:

> ```
> Ongoing: got 3
> Ongoing: got 4
> Ongoing: got 5
> WithHistory: got 1
> WithHistory: got 2
> WithHistory: got 3
> WithHistory: got 4
> WithHistory: got 5
> ```

However, using `BlockingCollection<T>` seems to be an overkill. Also the method above does not support completion, error handling and would cause deadlocks without `.SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)`.

Is there any better way to achieve it, without the described flaws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it is with `.Replay()`

```
void Main()
{
    var g = new Generator<int>();
    var ongoingItems = g.Items;
    var allItems = g.Items.Replay().RefCount();

    using(var tempSubscriber = allItems.Subscribe())
    {
        g.Push(1);
        g.Push(2);

        ongoingItems.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"Ongoing: got {x}"));
        allItems.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"WithHistory: got {x}"));

        g.Push(3);
        g.Push(4);
        g.Push(5);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`.Replay().RefCount()` produces an observable that will keep an internal queue for replaying, as long as there's a subscriber. If you have a persistent subscriber though (like your solution does in the `WithHistory` method), you have a memory leak. The best way to get around this is to have a temporary subscriber which automatically disconnects after you're no longer interested in the history.